# How to decide model performance on validation data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection, validation, hyperparameter

I have built several neural networks to decide what choice of a hyperparameter is best. I want to use the validation data (not test data) to do this.

To determine the performance of each model should one calculate the RMSE  for the trained networks on validation data or should one just consider the final value of the loss function on the validation set during training?

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: @Dave Mean Squared Error

Comment: RMSE and MSE are equivalent loss functions. Any model that scores better on one will score better on the other. Do you see why?

Comment: @ I mean should I calculate the RMSE for the *entire* validation set or use the *final* loss for the validation set. I think there is a difference in that case since the loss is only calculate on a batch of size 32 of data at a time.

Comment: It might be worth laying out the pros and cons explicitly in the question to make it clear how far you have gotten with it.